# Как с помощью Netfilter изменять пакеты в linux?

Tags: linux

Я так понимаю, необходимо написать модуль ядра. Из поисков я понял, что мы заставляем iptables все FORWARD пакеты идти к нам на прокси, а там уже можно делать с пакетами всё что угодно. 
У кого есть примеры или статьи, книги где описаны методы для реализации этой задачи?
Смысл в написании собственного балансировщика сети.

Comment: *У кого есть примеры или статьи, книги где описаны методы для реализации этой задачи?* — неужели вас действительно интересует этот вопрос — «у кого»?

Comment: А как Вы предлагаете его задать? Я хочу понять логику того, как это делается, чтобы уже после дописать под свои нужды.

Comment: [как задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Ну ок, чем пользоваться при изменении адреса назначения пакета?

Comment: Отвечаю: в интернете есть и статьи. книги вряд ли существуют. А вообще вам лучше копать в сторону NETMAP, вот например статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/183832/  Хотя можно и на уровне ядра, в виде модуля netfilter. Эот уже смотря от специфики задачи

Comment: Я видел описание модулей для ядра, но они были написаны аж в 2008 годах. За ссылку спасибо. По сути мне нужно изменить адрес назначения всего проходящего трафика.

Comment: Нормальных статей по модулям netfilter отродясь не видел. Берете исходники существующих модулей из ядра и переделываете под свои нужды. Просто статьи не могут угнаться за развитием ядра, а поддержанием обратной совместимости в ядре никто не озабочен. У меня есть один модуль, так пока шли 2я и часть 3й ветки его приходилось править примерно под каждую 10ю версию. Сейчас поспокойней стало, но часть функционала, который сейчас не нужен просто закоментарен, надоело править. Так что с NETMAP возможно спокойней и отлаживать проще, не придется перегружаться после каждой ошибки и kernel panic :)

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО! Изучу netmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтоб не использовать прокси рекомендую посмотреть захват пакетов в **nf_queue**. Данный модуль позволяет перенаправить выбранные пакеты в отдельную очередь в user-space, а там приложением уже вне ядра работать в пакетами. Описание технологии: http://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Queueing_to_userspace

Где-то на гитхабе был готовый http фильтр

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё два метода перенаправления на внешний прокси:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s ! squid-box -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to squid-box:3128
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s local-network -d squid-box -j SNAT --to iptables-box
iptables -A FORWARD -s local-network -d squid-box -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
```

и

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 80 -s squid-box
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j MARK --set-mark 3 -p tcp --dport 80
ip rule add fwmark 3 table 2
ip route add default via squid-box dev eth1 table 2
```

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html
Не думаю что стоит копировать описание с первоисточника, а то получится перевод статьи, а не простой ответ

Ключевые слова для поиска в Интернет: iptables external transparent proxy

Comment: Спасибо, но хотелось бы не использовать прокси сервера. Мне больше подходит модули для iptables.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/219435/ вот еще про прокси

Comment: @Vladimir кроме модулей есть еще очереди, добавил еще один ответ. пример мне попадался несколько раз классный и простой.. сейчас что-то не найду